# Get product list by ids in CMS page [ Magento 2 ]

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block, editor

I want to create cms page and will show products list as per given ids in admin editor.

Comment: have u tried to use  wiget at cms page

Comment: Please specify what you have do so far?

Comment: I want only to show products by ids like product_ids="1,5,8,52"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to some specific product to a cms page.

Then go to **admin>Content>CMS page**,Select your cms page,then open that cms page.

Then go to the **Content**  tab, click open widget icon.

[image]

**Insert Widget** select  Widget type **Catalog Product Listing**, after that at **Conditions**  select option **SKU** and set your SKUs at here.

Then  click on **insert widge**t button for insert your widget and then click on **Save Page** for save your page,then cache flush and check your page.

You donot need any code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Amit Bera, yours answer 100% right but I want to show by ids only.

Comment: Why you don't want to use SKU?. ID AND  SKU BOTH are like a unique key for a product.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the code bellow in your cms page

   ```
   {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/products-list.phtml"}}
   ```
2. Put your product collection in :

   ```
   app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/products-list.phtml
   ```

#### Update:

For testing, you can put the code bellow with the `objectManager` but it is not the good way, ones again just for testing:

```
<?php
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->setPageSize(5) // load just 5 products
                                ->load();
foreach ($collection as $product)
\Zend_Debug::dump($product->getData()); // echo $product->getId(); for Ids
?>
```

**The best way** to get them is to use a a **block**, create some function in that block then you retrieve that function in phtml like this : `$block->getMyCustomProducts()`

Content block:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function getMyCustomProducts()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(5); // fetching only 5 products
    return $collection;
}
```

> **Note:** don't forget to update the block class and template path (since you use a block, you should put that files in your custom
>   module) so:

```
{{block class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Block\{Blockname}" template="{Module}_{Name}::html/products-list.phtml"}} 

app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates/html/products-list.phtml
```

Comment: Can you share me code - how to get products list by ids in products-list.phtml

Comment: @Pukhraj Suthar Look my update please

Comment: @PЯINCƏ. Can u update the code of template file pls,

Comment: @jafarpinjar what do you mean by update the template file and why ?

Comment: @PЯINCƏ, you have the collection and how u display it in template file? i need tthat code

Comment: @jafarpinjar you call it fom the block in phtml like this = `$block->getMyCustomProducts()`