# Magento 2 Custom query to display selected product in Custom block

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, widgets, custom-block

I have some product ids . Currently I can display products in category using **{{block** . But now I am developing a custom block in

```
app/design/frontend/Alothemes/bencher6/Magento_Theme/templates/myphp/myphpcode.phtml
```

then in **myphpcode.phtml** i write the following query

```
$productId = 672;
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(672);
```

But I got ***Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found magento .***

So how can I list selected product block on a page .

When i try the following code

```
$product=$this->getLoadProduct(672);
echo $product->getName();
```

***Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on null***

I am calling this in cms page using following code

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::myphp/myphpcode.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Check this url
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/magento2-how-to-load-product-by-id

Comment: If you ever found see **Mage** then its M1 code not M2 ;)

Comment: it is m2 . I write the code . i dont know the m2 code . thats why i write m1 code

Answer (score 1):

please try with below code : ( you are using M1 code )

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1608519680 bytes) in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/bencher6/Magento_Theme/templates/myphp/myphpcode.phtml

Comment: increase memory limit 1024M in htaccess or php.ini

Answer (score 1):

**Try Below Code**:-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
foreach($collection as $product):
    if($product->getProductsShowAttribute() == 1):
        echo $product->getEntityId();
        echo $product->getName();
     endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: but where i can write the id

Comment: you can create a new attribute and this attribute set to product after that you get this product only you have to set this attibute

Comment: i have update my code please check it

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329168/add-a-new-dropdown-attribute-to-product-and-display-on-product-and-check-out-pag

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('product_id1','product_id2'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($products->getData());
?>
```

Comment: How can i call this in cms page . Before i am using following code {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::myphp/myphpcode.phtml"}}

Comment: i want the entire product block , not the name only

Comment: John, Please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the following code

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes this is working . But i want the entire product block , not the name only

Comment: You can replace `echo $product->getName();` to `echo $product->getData();` and check please.

Comment: We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

Comment: Can you describe what you need exactly?.

Comment: i want to show the entire product block with name, image , price etc . 
 
 
 For example if we want to display product in a cateogry , in cms block we write 
 
 {{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" ....etc ...   `category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`1`^]^]"}}
 
 But if we want display products with ids 32, 33, 34 what we will do ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241096/get-product-list-by-ids-in-cms-page-magento-2 You show this link.