# Magento 2 Custom Product block using SKU in cms page

Tags: magento2, blocks, products, cms, widget

I want to display custom product block in cms page . I have sku of the products . No how can i display this product in cms page . I know how to display one product using sku . But is it possible to display multiple product using sku ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241096/get-product-list-by-ids-in-cms-page-magento-2 You show this link.

Comment: You can open this link and you follow Amit Bera sir's solution. In this, you added your product directly in your cms page. You get easily show your product.

Comment: Why you don't want to use SKU?. ID and SKU both are like a unique key for a product.

Comment: You can add multiple SKUs in one widget. In Magento, all product have SKU.

Comment: could you please show example . How can i add multiple sku in one widget . Please paste the sample widget code . Because i am not able to do that

Comment: go to admin>Content>CMS page,Select your cms page,then open that cms page. Then go to the Content tab, click open widget icon.

Comment: i know this . This way i am inserting widget . But what i am saying is in this way  i can insert only one product in a widget . If i want to insert two products then i have to create 2 widget . That is the problem

Comment: No, You can click on the widget. Select catalog_type - catalog product list. After that, you add the condition in this. In this condition, you can choose SKU and add multiple SKU in this widget.

Comment: You only follow my step. You got solution.

Comment: Can you get a solution?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to some specific product to a cms page.

Then go to admin>Content>CMS page,Select your cms page,then open that cms page.

Then go to the Content tab, click open widget icon.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please follow my step and check, please.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: really thank you friend

Comment: @John You are most welcome. If this is the correct answer then up to my answer. So All person can use this solution.

Comment: Yes i modified my question based on your answer . I will post another question for to   do this same thing using php code in .phtml . Actually i am looking for that code

Comment: I think yes. This is the way to add multiple products in your CMS page directly. Without any code or errors.